# android - twitter4j getOAuthRequestToken() error

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

Why might this code throws exception? I don't have any idea. I entered the consumer key correctly and that's the only reason I can think that can cause this exception.  (currentRequestToken is RequestToken)

```
public String beginAuthorization() {
   try {
      if(null == currentRequestToken) {
         currentRequestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
      }
      return currentRequestToken.getAuthorizationURL();
   } catch (TwitterException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return null;
}
```

Comment: If you have an error message please add it to your post.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, in my case the solution was in my twitter account --> for developers --> My applications --> Settings --> Application type I changed to: Read, Write and Access direct messages.